# Determine whether the vectors are linearly independent 1-t+t³ ,-2+3t+t²+2t³ ,1+t²+5t³

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine whether the vectors are linearly independent 
Can you help me with this question?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question has already attracted several downvotes within minutes of your posting it. Bare problem statements like this that show no effort of your own to solve the problem look like you’re trying to outsource your homework and are not well received here: this question will likely be closed without an answer. If you’d like to prevent that, read through the [site tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) and edit this question to include the information described there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in F$ such that:
$a_1(1-t+t^3) + a_2(-2+3t +t^2+2t^3) + a_3(1+t^2 +5t^3) = 0+0t+0t^2+0t^3$,

That is,

$(a_1-2a_2+ a_3) + (-a_1+3a_2)t + (a_2+a_3)t^2 + (a_1+2a_2+5a_3)t^3 = 0 + 0t + 0t^2+ 0t^3.$

Now, we have

\begin{cases}
a_1 -2a_2+a_3 = 0 \\
-a_1+3a_2= 0 \\
a_2+a_3= 0  \\
a_1+2a_2+5a_3 = 0
\end{cases}

Now, if only solution is $a_1=a_2=a_3 =0$, then they are linearment independent, if not, they are linearment dependent. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try it by putting the coordinates into a matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1&1\\2&1&3&-2\\5&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Then Row-reduce: $\to\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1&1\\0&1&5&-4\\0&1&5&-4\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1&1\\0&1&5&-4\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

$\therefore$ they're dependent.